# Apple iOS 64-bit Upgrade of Existing Application

Tags: app-store

We are all aware of the requirement from Apple, that applications are required to be made 64-bit compatible. All existing applications in App Store needs to be made 64-bit compliant by June 1, 2015.

My question is that if, the application is not made 64-complaint by June 1, 2015, will the application be removed from App Store. What if we submit and update for the application with 64-bit compliance on May 30, 2015 after which Apple will take around 7-8 days for approval.

Can we release an upgrade after June 1, 2015 with 64-bit compliance? Can someone from the community please share some information on these questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  we can only guess and not really with certainly say what Apple will do.  
You should really ask Apple this.

Comment: So no official information is available regarding this. Every information from Apple that is available is that it has to be done by June 1, 2015, but it does not mention as to what happens to the apps which are not upgraded by June 1, 2015.

Comment: Until now Apple has never removed old Apps, bot may be they will. Ask Apple, because they are the only one's who now for sure.

Comment: Ok. I will check in the Apple Developer forum and confirm. If I get any further update from there then I will share the information in here too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understand you want to know, would be removed your app which is already in the store from App Store.

ItunesConnect is already has requirement about 64-bit, that is why now you **can't** release the app with out 64-bit, but this requirement is only in case of updates, the app which already in App Store won't be **removed**

Comment: Thanks for the update. But what happens if I do not update the app to 64-bit compliance even after June 1, 2015. Will the application still be there in App Store?

Comment: I think all will Ok, even if Apple decide remove apps without 64-bit, I'm sure they give you time for update your apps to version with 64-bit before removing.